# How to call a function whose name is given by the user through Python dictionary w/o if-elif statements

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program that asks for a command and a bunch of arguments from the user and executes it. Also, trying to be efficient by using python dictionaries. Here is my code:

```
command, *args = input().split()
args = list(map(int, args))
options = {'a': print(args[0]),
           'b': print(args[1]),
          }
options.get(command)
```

However, when I enter *'a 1 2'* in the input, the program compiles both *command a* and *command b*. Why is that? Can I fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The print commands are executed while your dictionary is being created. If you don't want that, don't use print inside the dictionary.

Comment: You can even omit the `options.get(command)` line and will get the same output...

Comment: If you want to pass arguments into a program, have a look into the built-in ‘argparse’ library.

Comment: Thank you all! I get it now.

Comment: Just curious why you want print inside the dict?

Comment: @mad_: I guess OP is just fiddling with functions inside dicts in general.

Comment: @mad_ It was just a test to see if I can do something like this. I am trying to build a list which can be modified by the user on run time (without if-elif statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone pointed out, You can use `eval`. However a better way would be to pass functions as values inside the dictionary and call them during retrieval. easiest way is using `lambda` to create a simple inline function.

Using your code, This would be something like:

```
command, *args = input().split()
args = list(map(int, args))
options = {'a': lambda args: print(args[0]),
           'b': lambda args: print(args[1]),
          }
options.get(command)(args)
```

In case you're not familiar with lambda expressions, it's just an easier way to create simple functions. for instance `lambda args: print(args[1])` evaluates to

```
def func(args):
    print(args[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question could be answered in the following way:

```
command, *args = input().split()
args = list(map(int, args))
options = {'a': (print, args[0]),
           'b': (print, args[1]),
          }

func, arg = options.get(command)
func(arg)
```

Now, type in `b 123 23` and only `23` will be printed.